# Generating a default parameter file (.yaml) for a given ROS package

Tags: ros, yaml, parameter, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

Is there an easy way to automatically generate a default parameter file (.yaml) for a given ROS package using the default parameter values and the descriptions of the parameters?
I was thinking this could be done for instance by parsing the text from the "parameters" section of the wiki page of the package, or maybe even directly from the source code.

Of course creating a file to set the parameters to their default values is redundant, but the generated file could be useful as a starting point for your own configuration, instead of going back and forth between your text editor and the wiki page to add parameters one by one and check their descriptions/default values.

For instance for the *amcl* package  (see section 3.1.5 "Parameters" of the wiki page http://wiki.ros.org/amcl )  the generated *amcl_config.yaml* file would be something like:

```
min_particles: 100 #Minimum allowed number of particles.
max_particles: 5000 #Maximum allowed number of particles. 
kld_err: 0.01 #Maximum error between the true distribution and the estimated distribution.
...
```

Am I missing something? Would it be practical/useful to add a "download default .yaml" link on the wiki pages?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174631/generating-a-default-parameter-file-(.yaml)-for-a-given-ros-package/) by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on ROS Answers with karma: 883 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not enough structure to automatically generate that sort of file.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-06-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [al-dev](https://answers.ros.org/users/18863/al-dev/) on 2014-06-24**:
Ok, too bad. Thanks.